# react-router-dom index Type 'true' is not assignable to type 'false'.ts(2322)

Tags: routes

I am using React Router 6 with typescript and `index` prop for `<Route>` is not taking true or boolean values

```
<Routes>
    <Route index>
        <h1>Here</h1>
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

It shows the following error

Answer (score 1):

To use `index` prop, you need to satisfy this

- Should not have `path` prop
- Should not have children but only an `element` prop

  ```
  <Route index element={<h1>Here</h1>}/>
  ```